# Seeking an intuitive understanding of formal definition of tangent

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am learning numerical optimization and I recently learned the formal definition of tangents. The definition is stated as follows:

Suppose $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is closed. If for all vector sequences $\left\{x_{i}\right\}$ satisfying $x_{i} \in \Omega$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty}x_{i} = x \in \Omega$, and for all positive scalar sequences $\left\{t_{i}\right\}$ satisfying $\lim_{i\to\infty}t_{i} = 0$, there exists a sequence $\left\{w_{i}\right\}$ satisfying $\lim_{i\to\infty}w_{i} = w$ and sequences $\left\{x_i + t_i w_i \right\}$ satisfy $x_i + t_i w_i \in \Omega$ for all $i$, then we say $w$ is tangent to $\Omega$ at $x \in \Omega$.

I can't associate this formal definition with an intuitive understanding, as it is too abstract. Could anyone provide an intuitive explanation for this definition?

Comment: @SangchulLee I think you need something quantified over all sequences that converge to $x,$ not just one. But the definition in the question has other things that differ from your more familiar form of the definition. Their $t_i$ is not necessarily $\lVert x_i-x\rVert$, and their $t_iw_i$ is not necessarily $x_i-x$.

Comment: @DavidK, Indeed it seems that I misread the definition a bit. I must have been half-awake when I wrote that. Thank you for pointing that out. / OP, As pointed out by DavidK, I parsed the definition incorrectly. Sorry for the confusion, and I will try to see how the definition can be put in a more intuitive way.

Comment: @SangchulLee Your definition is what I would expect. I don't quite understand the motivation for the definition from the other source. It seems to me there will be examples where the standard definition produces a tangent and the one in the question does not.

Comment: @DavidK, What I suspect is that the definition in OP kind of want to capture something similar to the *uniform differentiability*, which in 1-dimension looks like: $$\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to(a,a)\\x\neq y}}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee That may be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each given $p \in \Omega$ and $t > 0$, consider the set $\tilde{T}_{p,t}\Omega$ defined by

$$ \tilde{T}_{p,t}\Omega = \left\{ \frac{p' - p}{t} : p' \in \Omega \right\}. $$

Intuitively, this is the set obtained by zooming $\Omega$ about the point $p$ at the magnification $t^{-1}$. The following figure demonstrates $\tilde{T}_{p,t}\Omega$ for some different values of $p$ and $t$ (represented by the circle of radius $t$ centered at $p$):

[image: Different TOmega's]

Then the definition of the tangent tries to capture the "limit" of the picture of $\tilde{T}_{y,t}\Omega$ as $y \to x$ and $t \to 0$. Indeed, the definition is now rephrased as:

- A vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a tangent to $\Omega$ at $x$ if, for any $x_i \to x$ with $x_i \in \Omega$ and $t_i \to 0$ with $t_i > 0$, there exists a sequence $w_i \in \tilde{T}_{x_i,t_i}\Omega$ such that $w_i \to w$.

The definition becomes much more concise if we introduce the notion of distance between a point and a set. Let $\operatorname{dist}(x,A)=\inf\{\|x - a\| : a \in A\}$ denote the distance between the point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. Then

- The set $T_x\Omega$ of all tangent vectors to $\Omega$ at $x$ is given by
  $$ T_x\Omega = \{ w \in \mathbb{R}^n : \operatorname{dist}(w, \tilde{T}_{y,t}\Omega) \to 0 \text{ as $ (y, t) \to (x, 0)$ in $\Omega\times(0,\infty)$} \}. $$

It might be interesting to note that the right-hand side is nothing but the [Kuratowski limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence) of the sets $\tilde{T}_{y,t}\Omega$ as $(y,t) \to (x, 0)$ along $(y,t) \in \Omega\times(0,\infty)$.